# How can I wrap wheel item text onto multiple lines?

Tags: wheelnav.js

I am using the wheelnav.js library.  Some of the items in the wheel have text which needs to be wrapped onto a new line due to the length being too long.

I have tried using the <br /> html tag but it is rendered as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use \n.

```
myWheelnav.createWheel(["Short text","This is a\nlong text"]);
```

Comment: This does no longer work with this settings: `wheel2.titleCurved = true; wheel2.titleCurvedClockwise = true; wheel2.titleCurvedByRotateAngle = false;` (rc 1.8) (OK, just found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967553/how-to-curve-the-navtitle-along-the-path-using-wheelnav-js/51994795 :-))